# Request Blackout in MarkLogic

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

I am going through the MarkLogic admin guide and have few doubts about **Request Blackout**.

1. What is mean by Request Blackout.?
2. Real-time Use the case of Request Blackout.
3. What will happen with all the request triggered during Request Blackout.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like you may want to lock your child off the internet after 9pm, some companies want time of day included in security access policies.

https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin/session-login#id_48386